# About Asking Questions Then Not Responding

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I answered a question the other day, as did someone else (same question, I mean!). The OP has in his about me "Detail-oriented. I upvote detailed answers to my questions." I wrote a detailed response*, but he never responded to it (and often didn't respond to other people). So I wrote a comment saying "Does my answer sort your confusion? :)" to which he replied "nope it's not detailed". Firstly, as you can check yourself, (as far as I am aware) it covers all the required details. Secondly, (at least in my opinion) detailed answers are not necessarily the way forward: whenever I write a question, unless I'm extremely stuck, I shall always end it with something like "please leave a hint, not a full solution so that I can work it out myself" (obviously more politely than that!).

*I originally had my answer giving the method, then saying something like "I leave the details to you" (again, more politely!), but then I realised that the details were just one line and someone else had written them anyway, so I added them in.

The OP has now edited the question to include his method, and has not responded to any of the people.

Looking at the users other questions, I can see that he doesn't very often accept answers. A lot of his questions (not all, by any means) are related similarly. The question is now on hold because he has put a solution (again, ironically, without full details) in his question, so it's not clear what he's asking.

Is there anything that should be done about things like this? I'm not talking about just this one case, but in general. I have seen this sort of thing before where other users have spent considerable time helping someone who then ignores the helper, or even just closes the question after getting their answer (I know there's a meta question on the latter!).

I've seen before a user 'benched' - I can't remember exactly what for. Could potentially add an option under 'flag'? What do people think? :)

Comment: What do you want us to do about this? Stop whining, avoid this person, move on.

Comment: Please reread the post. It specifically says "I'm not talking about just this one case, but in general." I'm not asking for anything to be done about *this*. Just having individual users ignore some other individual users doesn't do anything to help the situation at all.

Comment: @SmileySam Then why does your post start with "this post is about a specific case"?!

Comment: It's referencing the specific case.

Comment: Ok, I'll give you that, it's badly worded. Let me change it. :)

Comment: One case, or in general, I still don't see what you want done. Short of sending the boys around to break their legs, that is.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Does that clarify it? :)

Comment: Flag users (*not meaning this specific one!*), add an option on the flagging, etc. I've seen some users 'benched' before. I'm not saying that is the right response for this situation, but your comment implies that there is no moderation on this site.

Comment: So I've updated it further so that no one can claim that I'm having a whinge about a specific user, but instead asking a general question.

Comment: @SmileySam It's clearer now, thanks. I still agree with Gerry though. If it bothers you, move along. I sometimes wonder why this happens as well, but in no way should anything be "done" about it, because of the multitude of possible causes.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Isn't that the same for lots of situations though? Eg, asking questions without adequate prior research or asking questions without giving any indication of personal attempts.

Comment: @Lord_Farin "because of the multitude of possible causes" Not convinced by the argument. I am aware that it is routinely proposed on this site but, if you pause to seriously think about it, you will see that the "possible causes" are not so many, or rather, that one or two causes suffice to explain a huge majority of cases. It might be so that nothing should be done about what the OP asks, but not for this reason.

Comment: @Did Forgive my brevity, I was commenting from my phone.

Comment: The user are speaking about has low votes on a few of the sites they use. I didn't look at all them but I imagine the trend is he same. Just avoid said user.

Comment: That's fine for those of us who have read this post... what I was suggesting is should there be some way of marking the user's profile? Eg, on eBay if you withdraw bids, then that comes up on your profile if people look; a bidder can then be blocked by individual sellers, but there are things in place to stop buyers who do this. Perhaps something similar (in principle) here?

Comment: At some point the feature of displaying the accept rate of a user was introduced. This caused more issues than it solved, so it was removed at some later point.

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19392/43351) to the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 7):

While it can be annoying when users do not reply (especially if they asked a question and one answered), there is not really much to be done about it in an active sense. In a passive sense, here is an idea:

Do not write content if you feel it is solely for the benefit of one user at one point in time. If you feel that your content could serve many, or also it was fun for you to create it, it is not that big a deal if OP stays idle.

Comment: That's good advice, thanks! I shall bare* that in mind in the future. (*I may have slightly spelt this 'bear' on first try... =P.)

Comment: In general, I have this mentality: I do ask quite a lot of questions (50 atm), and I get a lot of help from some very helpful people. I don't want to take this for granted, so want to give back to the community by answering questions myself. Unfortunately, the questions that I can answer (before there is already a full answer) are often by new users, so sometimes I get this! I shall certainly bare your advice in mind in the future though, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. And do not get discouraged!

Comment: Thanks man! Keep up your good work too! =D

Comment: @SmileySam "bear in mind" is correct, "bare in mind" is incorrect.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Oh yeah, well done Sam...